# Android Studio is not able to process res files after update

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

I have an issue with android studio  not being able to process the .xml files properly. I have restarted, cleared cache, created new project but still no answers. Here are some images to show case

> com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0-alpha05
>
> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.41

[image: ImageView cannot detect the launcher icon]

[image: Manifest file cannot detect the file]

[image: The files have this error that they have not been declared in the base resource folders]

Help where you can guys, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. Downgrade to AS 3.6 canary 3 if you are using canary 5 and the downgrade the gradle plugin to "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0-alpha03"

Check the issue : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136103084

If that did not work you can add this res manually and clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

please try  file —> invalidate caches and restart 
maybe it works, if not ,you can try to clean -> sync project

Comment: hello, I already did that... it still does not correct the errors.

Answer (score 0):

File - Invalidate Caches and Restart  then sync gradle and build project. And Use Stable Android Studio Version if you use Canary or any unstable version.

Comment: hello, I already did that... it still does not correct the errors.

Comment: do you use android stuido stable version or Beta or canary ?

Comment: it is canary 3.6.0-alpha05

Comment: so please use stable version it is most likely canary bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing issue. For a quick resume of your works you have to add the resources to the attrs resources manually or downgrade the AS 3.6 Canary 3 to start off. For your reference, I am adding issue link.

[Google issue tracker.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136103084)